# Elementary OS Workspace Manager Broke

Tags: window-manager, elementary-os

The workspace manager stopped working on my computer (Elementary OS Luna).  I suspected it may have had something to do with installing Tilda (Terminal Emulator), so I uninstalled that:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge  tilda
```

However it still didn't work even after I removed and purged and reinstalled gala (I think that's the program responsible for window management):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gala
sudo apt-get install  gala
```

My issue is this:  I can no longer switch workspaces, and although Super+S brings up the bar at the bottom (Workspace overview), it no longer shows any workspaces.  Super+right and Super+left don't work either.  The rest of the gala features work as they always have though.

http://elementaryos.org/journal/meet-gala-window-manager

Comment: UPDATE:  I restarted, and now NOTHING for Gala works!  How do I fix this?  Would reinstalling Elementary using the same passwords, usernames, partitions work?  (i.e. would that reinstall gala with all the defaults?)

UPDATE 2: So the reinstall worked, but I still can't get the Workspace management to work.  Back to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this problem and I believe I've pinned it down to happening after installing nVidia graphics driver. The behaviour I experienced was that I could not add any workspaces and when showing multitasking view, none of my open applications displayed (hence gala not letting me make more workspaces).

Reverting back to regular open source graphics driver immediately solved the problem for me.